# Annotate results with foreignkey

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'd like to filter an object in Django, and return it along with any objects for which the results are a ForeignKey. I'm not sure if annotation is what I need here, or something else.

This is my model:

```
class Dress(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(...)
  price = models.FloatField(...)

class ClothingSize(models.Model):
   code = models.CharField(...)

class DressSizeAvailable(models.Model):
  dress = models.ForeignKey(Dress)
  size = models.ForeignKey(ClothingSize)
```

Say I want to filter all dresses under $50, and then display them with the available sizes. What is the best way to do this?

I've got as far as this:

```
# In view
results = Dress.objects.filter(price__lt=50)
# How to annotate with available sizes?

# In template
{% for result in results %}
  {{ result.name }}, ${{ result.price }}
  Sizes: {{ ??? }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
### 1st solution (similar to Daniel Rosenthal's answer but with performances concern)
results = DressSizeAvailable.objects.filter(dress__price__lt=50).select_related('dress', 'size')
# then you can browse your DressSizeAvailables as you wish in your template. The select related allows you NOT TO query the database again when you generate your template

### 2nd solution
results = Dress.objects.filter(price__lt=50).prefetch_related('dresssizeavailable_set__dress')

{% for dress in results  %}
    {{ dress.name }}, ${{ dress }}
    Sizes: <ul>
        {% for dsa in dress.dresssizeavailable_set %}
            <!-- Thanks to the prefetch_related, we do not query the base again here -->
            <li>{{ dsa.size.code }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to put an `all` on the end of `{% for dsa in dress.dresssizeavailable_set.all %}` for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to give your template a queryset (or something similar) of `DressSizeAvailable` objects. So first you'll need to get all the `Dress` objects you're interested, and then filter `DressSizeAvailable` based on those Dresses

so in your view:

```
dresses = Dress.objects.filter(price__lt=50)
dress_size_available = []
for dress in dresses:
    available = DressSizeAvailable.objects.filter(dress=dress)
    dress_size_available.append(available)
```

Then render your template, passing it the variable `dress_size_available`

Your template can then be rather simple.

```
{% for dsa in dress_size_available %}
    {{ dsa.dress.name }}, ${{ dsa.dress.price }}
    Size: {{ dsa.size }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: __In views.py:__ One DB query in line 1, anothor for each iteration => N+1 DB queries. __In the template.html:__ 3 queries for each iteration of the for loop => 3N DB queries. __Total:__ 1+4N queries to your database !! I Guess your database is on the same host than your application server, or you performances will be very poor :)

Comment: Yes, I was going to ask - isn't iterating over the queryset inefficient?

Comment: To be efficient while iterating over the queryset, be sure to add __select_related()__ for direct foreign keys, and __prefetch_related()__ for reverse foreign keys and m2m relations. See their doc here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related. Everytime you call ".<related_table>" on an object from a queryset, if you didn't use those two functions to already include them in the queryset, Django will refetch the DB for them.